# Execute all the oozie actions on the same node

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I need to execute an oozie workflow to process some files using a java program, but before execute the jar, I need to get the files from HDFS, and after been processed delete them.

I came up with this workflow with 3 shell action, and it runs, but just the first shell action works, after digging into the log files, I realized that the shell action 2 and 3 never were executed. So unless they where executed on different nodes, there is no reason why they should not work, I taste the 3 shell scripts in the edge node and they work.

```
 <start to="shellAction"/>
<action name="shellAction">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">
        <exec>${shellCmd1}</exec>
        <file>${shellCmd1}#${shellCmd1}</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="shellAction2"/>
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
    <action name="shellAction2">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">
             <exec>java</exec>
             <argument>arg</argument>
             <argument>./${EXEC}:`classpath` MainClass</argument>
             <argument>"${arg1}"</argument>
             <argument>"${arg2}"</argument>
             <argument>${arg3}</argument>
             <file>${EXEC}#${EXEC}</file>
        </shell>
        <ok to="shellAction3"/>
        <error to="shellAction3" />
     </action>
     <action name="shellAction3">
            <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">
            <exec>${shellCmd3}</exec>
            <file>${shellCmd3}#${shellCmd3}</file>
     </shell>
       <ok to="end"/>
       <error to="fail" />
     </action>
```

So my question is, is there a way to guarantee the execution of those 3 actions on the same container/node?

Comment: _"before execute the jar, I need to get the files from HDFS"_ >> no you don't. Just use the HDFS Java API and open an `InputStream` straight from an HDFS `Path`.

Comment: _"they where executed on different node"_ >> yes, that's the whole point of running your workflow on a distributed system, all steps are expected to run on random nodes and use only HDFS for persistence.

Comment: Why don't you run the 3 steps on an Edge Node if you cannot cope with distributed execution? Or if you really want to use Oozie to make things complex, and don't want to tap HDFS from Java because _"OMG that's **programming**, yuck"_ then just run a single shell Action with a Java command line in the middle.